# How to load all the known Colors with in a Listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I want load all the predefined colors in my `listBox`. I am using same thing for fonts too, but I don't know about the color. I mean, I don't know how to enumerate all the known Colors.

```
foreach (FontFamily F in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
        {
            ListBoxItem l = new ListBoxItem();
            l.Content = F.ToString();
            l.FontFamily = F;
            listbox1.Items.Add(l);
        }
```

How to do same thing for `Color`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take color from [KnownColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor.aspx)

```
KnownColor[] colors  = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
foreach(KnownColor knowColor in colors)
{
  Color color = Color.FromKnownColor(knowColor);

    ListBoxItem listItem = new ListBoxItem();
    listItem.Content = color.ToString();
    listItem.Color = color ;
    listbox1.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

[Here](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1405.htm) is an example for Retrieving Colors.

Answer (score 2):

`Color` is a structure and hence is not in the scope of `IEnumerable`, so you will have to something like.:

```
    foreach (Color color in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
    {
        ListBoxItem l = new ListBoxItem();
        l.Content = color.Name;
        l.Color = color;
        listbox1.Items.Add(l);
    }
```

Comment: i am using this code in WPF but it show me Error:                 The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: `KnownColor` is an `enum` in C# that stores the values of all the Named Colors. @user1050667

Answer (score 1):

```
    var colorProperties = Colors.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    var colors = colorProperties.Select(prop => (Color)prop.GetValue(null, null));
    foreach(Color c in colors)
    {
        ListBoxItem l = new ListBoxItem();
        l.Content = c.ToString();
        l.Color = c;
        listbox1.Items.Add(l);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well

[Link to Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19356/Multi-color-DropDownList-using-C)

```
private List finalColorList()
{ 
    string[] allColors = Enum.GetNames(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor));
    string[] systemEnvironmentColors = 
        new string[(
        typeof(System.Drawing.SystemColors)).GetProperties().Length];

    int index = 0;

    foreach (MemberInfo member in (
        typeof(System.Drawing.SystemColors)).GetProperties())
    {
        systemEnvironmentColors[index ++] = member.Name;            
    }

    List finalColorList =  new List();

    foreach (string color in allColors)
    {
        if (Array.IndexOf(systemEnvironmentColors, color) < 0)
        {
            finalColorList.Add(color);
        }                           
    }
    return finalColorList;
}
```